# Speed MySQL SELECT query

Tags: mysql, select

I am having a MySQL query that is comparing values between two tables.
The query works fine, but it is kind of slow.

**This is the query**

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE questions.id NOT IN (SELECT answers.qid FROM answers where answers.account = 'Account') and FIND_IN_SET(questions.lang,'en,de') and category = 'Cat' order by section
```

My structure looks like this

**TABLE QUESTIONS**

[image]

**TABLE ANSWERS**

[image]

I have around 900 records in both tables that the query runs.
But the query execution is 5.8475 seconds.

I was wondering if I have something in my query that I can optimize in order to make its execution faster.

Comment: I don't know your field list on your `questions` table, but I can guess that you need something like this `SELECT q.id, q.lang, q.category, q.section FROM questions q 
inner join answers an on(q.id = an.id and an.account <> "Account")
where (q.lang = "en" or q.lang = "de") and q.category = "Cat"
order by q.section`

Comment: @Hackerman I have tried your query, but for some reason, it is giving me a wrong result. Basically, I am using all the data apart from the date column, that's why I used asterisks. However, your query is 5 times faster :) I just need to find why it is giving the wrong result.

Comment: I guess the wrong result comes from the `INNER JOIN`. Hackerman's query only returns questions which have answers, but not questions without any answers record. I posted an answer with a query I think returns the correct result and is faster, but I'm just assuming as I have not tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT questions.*
FROM questions
    LEFT JOIN answers
        ON questions.id = answers.qid AND answers.account = 'Account'
WHERE answers.id IS NULL AND questions.category = 'Cat' AND questions.lang IN('de', 'en')
ORDER BY questions.section
```

I guess that a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `NOT IN()` is faster, as Hackerman suggested in his comment. Also I assume that `IN()` is faster than the `FIND_IN_SET`, but I have not tested nor researched it.

Comment: Yeap, that worked... Only one thing was wrong... the answers column I am comparing the id of the question is `answers.qid` not `answers.id`. One question: Why do we need `answers.id IS NULL`? Thanks @R. Horber

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer. To your question: To filter out the answers with `account = 'Account'` (the subquery in your question). I use the construct `LEFT JOIN someTable ... WHERE someTable.id IS NULL` for something like "exclude records that match some criteria `someTable`", I define "some criteria" to the JOIN's ON clause.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. The query executes very fast - 0.1433 seconds... comparing to the original query 5.8475 seconds.